# merging two folder directory using git

Tags: git, git-merge

So I have folder structure as follows

`main -- .git
  |_ /app
       |_ .git
  |_ /server
       |_ .git`

I initialized git for both sub-directory and main directory. How can I merge all commit by preserving all commits history and files into main folder .git

I want only one .git branch instead of multiple branches.

note: I have manually created folders not with git branch.

Comment: It’s messed up from git point of view  — either do everything in one repo or use sub-modules. The current structure is broken.

Comment: @0andriy I absolutely understand your view, I made mess because of my inexperience but I dont know how to clear this up. I am not equipped much beyond basic git operations. if I copy server folder into app folder and then `git  add & commit` file would at least sort this into one single git branch I suppose. my server folder is still light with only one file and few commits. probably I can merge them with basic add & commit operation. I am just seeking advice before I mess up more. Referring this, scared to implement. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried resolving this issue by just doing `rm -rf .git` from server folder and moved `/server` to master and followed with `git add .` & `git commit -m 'server'` . I am not sure this is the best practice but it didn't affect my commit log history. I hope this is the right way to do.